Build a file Browser button in Qt Designer 6
Build a file Browser  Button and configure a signal/slot functionality in Qt Designer
I've tried creating signals with "Edit Signals/Slots" and I add mybutton_cliked as a receiver but when I run the code I got an attribute error: QMAINWINDOW object has no attribute "mybutton_cliked "
to pass from qt designer to python code I use this commad
python -m PyQt6.uic.pyuic -x Main_Window.ui -o Main_Window.py 

so I got this :
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1164, 848)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(146, 250, 255);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.graphicsView_4 = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.graphicsView_4.setObjectName("graphicsView_4")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.graphicsView_4, 1, 4, 1, 1)
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 2, 0, 1, 5)
        self.graphicsView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName("graphicsView")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.graphicsView, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        self.graphicsView_2 = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.graphicsView_2.setObjectName("graphicsView_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.graphicsView_2, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.graphicsView_3 = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.graphicsView_3.setObjectName("graphicsView_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.graphicsView_3, 1, 3, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Yu Gothic UI Semibold")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(parent=MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1164, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(parent=MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(MainWindow.mybutton_cliked) # type: ignore
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Browser"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


It's normally not necessary to create new signals in Designer. Also, since it's just a button, there's really no need for this: just connect its clicked signal in the code logic. If you need more comprehensive help, please provide a proper [mre] including the UI file and the Python script (please ensure that it's both minimal and reproducible: we don't need the full code).

Refrering (pyqt5)to :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42046092/how-do-i-create-a-signal-to-open-a-qfiledialog-in-qt-designer

The file you posted is just the pyuic output. You're not expected to use it as your main script, and the error you receive is because creating the mybutton_cliked "slot" has to be done in the code logic. In fact, if you closely look at the answer you linked, the function is implemented in a subclass that inherits from the pyuic class, and that properly provides the "custom slot" defined in the UI. Follow the official guidelines about using Designer, implement the function in a subclass and create the connection in code.
